# pybind11 cannot open shared object file when installing the package in editable mode

Tags: c++, python-3.x, cmake, pybind11

I am working on a c++ project which supports python API based on the package [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11). My plan is to build a c++ shared library from c++ source files and then use wrapper to build the API. Here is a step-by-step minimum example deviated from [the repo of pybind11 cmake example](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example).

1. The folder hierarchy and files' content are almost exactly the same as the [example project](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example), but I show them all here for the sake of completeness:

- Hierarchy: minimum code example.

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── extern
│   └── pybind11
├── pybind11_minimum_example.cpp
├── pyproject.toml
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── Student.cpp
    └── Student.hpp
```

- `src/CMakeLists.txt`: complie and build shared library.

```
file(GLOB SOURCES "./*.cpp" "./*.hpp")

# Generate the shared library from the sources
add_library(srclib SHARED ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(srclib PRIVATE  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
```

- `src/Student.hpp`: declaration of `Student`.

```
#include <string>

class Student {
private:
  std::string name;

public:
  Student(std::string);
  const std::string get_name() const;
  virtual void display();
};
```

- `src/Student.cpp`: definition of `Student`.

```
#include <src/Student.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Student::Student(string name) : name(name) {}

void Student::display() {
  cout << "A student with name " << this->name << endl;
}

const std::string Student::get_name() const { return this->name; }
```

- `pyproject.toml`:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=42", "wheel", "ninja", "cmake>=3.12",]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

- `CMakeLists.txt`: The root builds the project.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4...3.18)
project(pybind11_minimum_example VERSION 0.0.1)

add_subdirectory(src)

add_subdirectory(./extern/pybind11)
pybind11_add_module(pybind11_minimum_example pybind11_minimum_example.cpp)
target_link_libraries(pybind11_minimum_example PRIVATE srclib)
target_include_directories(pybind11_minimum_example PRIVATE  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

# EXAMPLE_VERSION_INFO is defined by setup.py and passed into the C++ code as a
# define (VERSION_INFO) here.
target_compile_definitions(pybind11_minimum_example PRIVATE VERSION_INFO=${EXAMPLE_VERSION_INFO})
```

- `pybind11_minimum_example.cpp`: binding code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <src/Student.hpp>

namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(pybind11_minimum_example, m) {
  py::class_<Student>(m, "Student")
        .def(py::init<const std::string &>())
        .def("display", &Student::display)
        .def("get_name", &Student::get_name);
}
```

- `setup.py`: copy and paste from [example](https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example/blob/master/setup.py)

```
import os, re, subprocess, sys
from pathlib import Path
from setuptools import Extension, setup
from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext

# Convert distutils Windows platform specifiers to CMake -A arguments
PLAT_TO_CMAKE = {
    "win32": "Win32",
    "win-amd64": "x64",
    "win-arm32": "ARM",
    "win-arm64": "ARM64",
}

# A CMakeExtension needs a sourcedir instead of a file list.
# The name must be the _single_ output extension from the CMake build.
# If you need multiple extensions, see scikit-build.
class CMakeExtension(Extension):
    def __init__(self, name: str, sourcedir: str = "") -> None:
        super().__init__(name, sources=[])
        self.sourcedir = os.fspath(Path(sourcedir).resolve())

class CMakeBuild(build_ext):
    def build_extension(self, ext: CMakeExtension) -> None:
        # Must be in this form due to bug in .resolve() only fixed in Python 3.10+
        ext_fullpath = Path.cwd() / self.get_ext_fullpath(ext.name)  # type: ignore[no-untyped-call]
        extdir = ext_fullpath.parent.resolve()

        # Using this requires trailing slash for auto-detection & inclusion of
        # auxiliary "native" libs

        debug = int(os.environ.get("DEBUG", 0)) if self.debug is None else self.debug
        cfg = "Debug" if debug else "Release"

        # CMake lets you override the generator - we need to check this.
        # Can be set with Conda-Build, for example.
        cmake_generator = os.environ.get("CMAKE_GENERATOR", "")

        # Set Python_EXECUTABLE instead if you use PYBIND11_FINDPYTHON
        # EXAMPLE_VERSION_INFO shows you how to pass a value into the C++ code
        # from Python.
        cmake_args = [
            f"-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY={extdir}{os.sep}",
            f"-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE={sys.executable}",
            f"-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE={cfg}",  # not used on MSVC, but no harm
        ]
        build_args = []
        # Adding CMake arguments set as environment variable
        # (needed e.g. to build for ARM OSx on conda-forge)
        if "CMAKE_ARGS" in os.environ:
            cmake_args += [item for item in os.environ["CMAKE_ARGS"].split(" ") if item]

        # In this example, we pass in the version to C++. You might not need to.
        cmake_args += [f"-DEXAMPLE_VERSION_INFO={self.distribution.get_version()}"]  # type: ignore[attr-defined]

        if self.compiler.compiler_type != "msvc":
            # Using Ninja-build since it a) is available as a wheel and b)
            # multithreads automatically. MSVC would require all variables be
            # exported for Ninja to pick it up, which is a little tricky to do.
            # Users can override the generator with CMAKE_GENERATOR in CMake
            # 3.15+.
            if not cmake_generator or cmake_generator == "Ninja":
                try:
                    import ninja  # noqa: F401

                    ninja_executable_path = Path(ninja.BIN_DIR) / "ninja"
                    cmake_args += [
                        "-GNinja",
                        f"-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH={ninja_executable_path}",
                    ]
                except ImportError:
                    pass

        else:

            # Single config generators are handled "normally"
            single_config = any(x in cmake_generator for x in {"NMake", "Ninja"})

            # CMake allows an arch-in-generator style for backward compatibility
            contains_arch = any(x in cmake_generator for x in {"ARM", "Win64"})

            # Specify the arch if using MSVC generator, but only if it doesn't
            # contain a backward-compatibility arch spec already in the
            # generator name.
            if not single_config and not contains_arch:
                cmake_args += ["-A", PLAT_TO_CMAKE[self.plat_name]]

            # Multi-config generators have a different way to specify configs
            if not single_config:
                cmake_args += [
                    f"-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_{cfg.upper()}={extdir}"
                ]
                build_args += ["--config", cfg]

        if sys.platform.startswith("darwin"):
            # Cross-compile support for macOS - respect ARCHFLAGS if set
            archs = re.findall(r"-arch (\S+)", os.environ.get("ARCHFLAGS", ""))
            if archs:
                cmake_args += ["-DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES={}".format(";".join(archs))]

        # Set CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL to control the parallel build level
        # across all generators.
        if "CMAKE_BUILD_PARALLEL_LEVEL" not in os.environ:
            # self.parallel is a Python 3 only way to set parallel jobs by hand
            # using -j in the build_ext call, not supported by pip or PyPA-build.
            if hasattr(self, "parallel") and self.parallel:
                # CMake 3.12+ only.
                build_args += [f"-j{self.parallel}"]

        build_temp = Path(self.build_temp) / ext.name
        if not build_temp.exists():
            build_temp.mkdir(parents=True)

        subprocess.run(
            ["cmake", ext.sourcedir] + cmake_args, cwd=build_temp, check=True
        )
        subprocess.run(
            ["cmake", "--build", "."] + build_args, cwd=build_temp, check=True
        )

setup(
    name="pybind11_minimum_example",
    version="0.0.1",
    ext_modules=[CMakeExtension("pybind11_minimum_example")],
    cmdclass={"build_ext": CMakeBuild},
    python_requires=">=3.8",
)
```

- `extern/pybind11`: pybind11 as git submodule.

2. Create, activate and update virtual env:

```
python3 -m venv venv_pybind11_example && source venv_pybind11_example/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
```

3. Install with pip command `python3 -m pip install .` and run python code.

- Two folder, `build/` and `pybind11_minimum_example.egg-info/`, are generated.
- Run with python.

```
>>> import pybind11_minimum_example
>>> s = pybind11_minimum_example.Student("John")
>>> s.display()
A student with name John
```

Everything works fine so far.

4. Install with pip command in editable mode `python3 -m pip install -e .` and run python code.

- One file `pybind11_minimum_example.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` and one folder `pybind11_minimum_example.egg-info/` are generated.
- Run with python.

```
>>> import pybind11_minimum_example
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libsrclib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this?

**Update:**
In normal installation mode, the shared library *.so is inside virtual env's `lib/python3.8/site-packages/`.

```
>>> import pybind11_minimum_example
>>> print(pybind11_minimum_example.__file__)
./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pybind11_minimum_example.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

And there are two `libsrclib.so` inside the following two folders:

```
./build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-38/libsrclib.so
./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/libsrclib.so
```

While in editable installation mode, there is no *.so file inside `./venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/`. But there is `pybind11_minimum_example.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` in the parent folder. And `sys.path` includes parent folder. And there is no `libsrclib.so` everywhere in the parent and its subsequent folders.

Answer (score 0):

In this setup I can't see:

- where the c++ library is copied inside the python package and referenced in the `setup.py`.
- How your pybind wrapper library `pybind11_minimum_example` can load `libsrclib.so` since you don't set the rpath (linux) or loader_path (mac).
- Also on windows you should use a static library for `srclib` (to avoid all the import/export stuff + dynamic loading how to ?)

An alternative would be to use a CMake based orchestrated build and maybe use my template project: https://github.com/Mizux/cmake-pybind11

Thing to look (and replicate in your setup otherwise):

1. Since everything is orchestrated by CMake so basically the workflow is

   1. I build all C++ and pybind11 libraries as usual then
   2. generate a `<BUILDIR>/python/foo` where I put(copy/configure) all the
      python stuff to generate my python package layout then
   3. call `python setup.py` **from** CMake to "just" package everything in
      a wheel (ed from python point of view all libraries are prebuilt).
      note: [README doc](https://github.com/Mizux/cmake-pybind11#build-process) was based on my cmake python SWIG, on my way to adapt few diagrams to pybind11...
2. To copy all internal library in a `.libs/` directory of the package

```
# Don't need to copy static lib on Windows.
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E $<IF:$<STREQUAL:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:srclib,TYPE>,SHARED_LIBRARY>,copy,true>
$<$<STREQUAL:$<TARGET_PROPERTY:srclib,TYPE>,SHARED_LIBRARY>:$<TARGET_SONAME_FILE:Foo>>
  ${PYTHON_PROJECT}/.libs
```

ref: https://github.com/Mizux/cmake-pybind11/blob/423beda3d9b5439899cdc178447f71873cbe1afb/cmake/python.cmake#L134-L150

note: in order for pybind11 wrapper to find the library I need to update the RPATH using this code: https://github.com/Mizux/cmake-pybind11/blob/423beda3d9b5439899cdc178447f71873cbe1afb/FooBar/python/CMakeLists.txt#L3-L15

3. List them in the `setup.py` using "package_data" field:

```py
  package_data={
  '@PYTHON_PROJECT@':[$<$<NOT:$<PLATFORM_ID:Windows>>:'.libs/*'>],
  '@PYTHON_PROJECT@.foo':['$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:pyFoo>'],
  '@PYTHON_PROJECT@.bar':['$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:pyBar>'],
  '@PYTHON_PROJECT@.foobar':['$<TARGET_FILE_NAME:pyFooBar>'],
  },
```

ref: https://github.com/Mizux/cmake-pybind11/blob/423beda3d9b5439899cdc178447f71873cbe1afb/python/setup.py.in#L25-L30

So, IMHO, you need to replicate this step or migrate to my workflow.
Hope it will help...